# Problem in publishing chrome extension to chrome webstore with key field in manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

We are trying to publish our chrome extension on webstore but it's giving an error while uploading zip the error is that can't upload chrome extension with key field in manifest.json .
The key field we added to manifest.json was for Oauth2, we used for authentication of users with google.
Now when we published our extension without key field it's being uploaded without any error but Oauth is not working.
Any of you has any idea about this problem please help us.

Comment: The [key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) field in `manifest.json` is not the one related to Oauth2, but to control the unique ID of the extension

Comment: It was method for Oauth2 written in chrome documentation \

Comment: key field according to them is required for Oauth2, if we remove that key field from manifest the Oauth2 stops working

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth#upload_to_dashboard As you can see in this link

Comment: When you upload your extension to CWS, you have to remove the `key` field, as the key is assigned automatically by CWS. Once uploaded, you can check and copy the assigned key from the Developer Dashboard and use it for your OAuth2 purposes, just as it says in the documentation you linked.

Comment: i used this for Oauth2 purposes but when we completed the extension and removed the key and published it now the publish version's authentication not working

Comment: You have to upload it to CWS first, to obtain the CWS `key`. Then, with that key, you set up your OAuth credentials, just like the documentation you linked says.